# Is there a more effective way to compare a string

Tags: vb.net

EDIT: I have noticed, as I make some changes as suggested below, the program is only using 12% CPU and barely any Read/Write but still kinda slow, I ran the program on 4 files at once using threads, doing slightly less than 4x the work and using 62% cpu, I do have a 100ms timer updating a progress bar and label. Could this be impacting performance in someway? This particular program only does this one task, so has a label, timer and a progress bar, its executed everytime a file arrives for it.

I have 655,000 "Words" in a file. I want to cross reference a user provided "word" to see if I can find a match in the file.

At current, I simply open the file, and read line by line, checking if the values are the same.

But this takes a long long time to go through the file.

Is there a faster way to do comparisons? Should I read the whole file, then split, and compare?

I attempted to "Index" the word file, but this also takes forever. Code below

I run it in a separate thread

The file grows very fast, two hours ago it was 10,000 "Words" I would assume it will get into the 10's of millions

I use the term "Words" because the file contains data from my first neuronet AI so referencing a word search wouldn't work unfortunately.

```
Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
        NewWord = (sr.ReadLine())
        FirstLetter = NewWord(0)
        Wordlength = NewWord.Length

        If Wordlength < 5 Then
            writefile = "5.txt"
        End If
        If Wordlength = 6 Then
            writefile = "6.txt"
        End If
        If Wordlength = 7 Then
            writefile = "7.txt"
        End If
        If Wordlength = 8 Then
            writefile = "8.txt"
        End If
        If Wordlength = 9 Then
            writefile = "9.txt"
        End If
        If Wordlength = 10 Then
            writefile = "10.txt"
        End If
        If Wordlength = 11 Then
            writefile = "11.txt"
        End If
        If Wordlength >= 12 Then
            writefile = "12.txt"
        End If


        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "a" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\A\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "b" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\B\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "c" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\C\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "d" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\D\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "e" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\E\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "f" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\F\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "g" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\G\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "h" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\H\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "i" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\I\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "j" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\J\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "k" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\K\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "l" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\L\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "m" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\M\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "n" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\N\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "o" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\O\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "p" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\P\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "q" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\Q\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "r" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\R\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "s" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\S\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "t" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\T\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "u" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\U\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "v" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\V\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "w" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\W\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "x" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\X\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "y" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\Y\"
        End If
        If LCase(FirstLetter) = "z" Then
            Writepath = "H:\Dictionary\Z\"
        End If

        outputpath = Writepath & writefile



        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(outputpath)
            sw.WriteLine(NewWord)
        End Using
        progressvalue = progressvalue + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: I'd read the file into a HashSet and look it up in there. If you find the number of words growing significantly, you may want to look into using a database instead of a local flat file

Comment: I'd replace all those `If` with a `Select Case` so it will not have to check all other conditions.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought about a database, but the end file will have 
1.4534931852847813494150390625e+58 Entries, I'm using many nodes to check smaller file chunks, Hence why attempting to split.
I had looked into the type of programming required for such a feat, and I couldn't understand a bar of it.  I will look into a hashset now, Thankyou

Comment: Thanks Filburt, looking into that will no doubt be a help over all my neuronet coding.

Comment: "the end file will have 1.4534931852847813494150390625e+58 Entries". Oh no it won't: do a quick calculation to work out how much storage that would need ;) And maybe consider that there are "only" ~10^50 atoms making up our planet.

Comment: Lots and lots of storage. Yes, That's why everything has to be split between many pc's to accommodate workload. Like calculating pie, its not anticipated it will ever end, or stop growing the data set, till something blows up. the number is the computed number for possibilities. The "End Game"

Comment: Perhaps if you gave us an overview of what you want to achieve we could suggest something which is practicable. Otherwise, you could blow up one computer (but this is not chemistry.se) and your task would be complete.

Comment: Well, I don't know if your familiar with the saying.

Comment: If you have a infinite amount of monkeys hitting keyboards on a infinite amount of pc's for a infinite amount of time, one of them will eventually write shakespare.

Basically what my neuronet is doing, Its applying a brute force approach to a problem, And giving answers, A lot of them, the blocks of answers are split off into files every 655,000 calculations, and handed down to be further split into smaller files, so other programs can take smaller files, and look for relevant answers.

Comment: The Neuronet weights its data output with a letter of the alphabet to make dividing into 26 easy

And then I have a statistical breakdown of % output based on lengths, so I can breakdown into basically "Equal" file sizes.

My Bottleneck is currently splitting data into the smaller chunks, I can't process the 655'000 lines as fast as the neuronet spits them out, and the end of line PC's sit idle for 20 odd minutes between chunks.

Hopefully that makes some sence?

Had to keep it short, there is limits.

Comment: A couple of years of research might decrease the run-time of your program significantly. I am familiar with the infinite monkey theorem and why it [doesn't hold for this universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem#Probabilities). Just be careful that you don't enumerate the [The Nine Billion Names of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Billion_Names_of_God) :)

Answer (score 1):

Hash data structure (for example `HashSet` in .NET) would be the fastest way to add and check words, but that will eventually run out of memory as you add more words.

Database should be best as the words will be indexed and you can access it from multiple machines.

Using file system for that will most likely be the slowest way, but I am guessing that using folder names instead of files should be faster. For example, for the word `Foo`, the path will be `"H:\Dictionary\F\O\O\"` (upper or lowercase does not matter on most popular file systems that I know of), but it will also use much more space as each folder will have separate metadata information and settings.

If the project has some budget, you can search for better solutions like Google BigQuery.

Comment: If he wants to maintain a unique set a Hashset is better than the HashTable as it doesn't allow for dup values... Also a HashTable is syncronized and has a cost also they can only be accessed by only one thread at a time which would limit the speed of checking the words significantly.

Comment: @Zaggler I mean it as a general concept not limited to the .NET framework, but I am not sure what would be the most obvious term for it.